# Which is the size of a digital certificate with the private/public keys?

Tags: digital-signature, public-key, digital-certificate

I am involved in a project in which our employees need to sign specific documents using their digital signatures. To do this, each employee will have a RFID card to store their certificate with the private/public keys. My question is related to the size of such certificate. I have been browsing around but I have not been able to find an answer.

Which is the size of a file that contains the digital certificate with both the public and the private signatures?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are aware that the private key is *not* part of the certificate?

Comment: What I mean is that the employee will have to sign the documents using his personal RFID card so we need to store his private key in such card.

Comment: The size of the keys depends on the signing algorithm (with parameters) used. The size of the certificate furthermore depends on what information your CA wants to put into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the certificate and a private key depends on algorithm, key length and additional information such as names of the issuer and subject, various URLs (for CRL and OCSP shecks etc) placed to the certificate. So it is reasonable to assume the size of one certificate to be between 2 and 4 Kb (I would reserve at least 4Kb per cert + key).